# Factorizing two variables with expressions

Tags: prime-factorization

So the question is ab - 4a + 6b - 24. I'm not really sure where to start. I thought of adding the 4 and 6 together which is equals to 10ab but then I don't really know where to go from their.

Comment: Is that supposed to a $24$ instead of $34$? If not, I don't see how that's going to be factored.

Comment: $$ab-4a+6b-24=a(b-4)+6(b-4)$$  So,it  should be $24,$ not $34$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grouping the terms with $a$ in them and factoring $a$ out gives

$$a(b-4) + 6b-24.$$

Factor out $6$ from $6b-24$, and continue to get a factorization.

Comment: so it will be: a(b-4) + 6(b-4) = (b-4) - (a-6) = b(a-6) - 4(a-6)

Comment: Yep, and you can factor $b-4$ out from both terms.

Comment: so the final answer would be: b(a-6) - 4(a-6) @symmetricuser

Comment: Should be $(a+6)(b-4)$.